# Redraw pager when I hide the sidebar in Mutt?

Tags: mutt

I added a macro to my `.muttrc` that toggles the sidebar with <kbd>b</kbd>:

```
macro index b "<enter-command>toggle sidebar_visible<enter>"
macro pager b "<enter-command>toggle sidebar_visible<enter>"
```

FWIW, this would have also worked:

```
macro index, pager b "<enter-command>toggle sidebar_visible<enter>"
```

but in the pager, when I toggle the sidebar off, the page doesn't re-draw until I go back to the index, so instead of a sidebar I have a big swath of nothing, or the sidebar just pops up on top of the message, hiding 200px of it. Is there something I can add to this macro that will re-draw the screen when I toggle the sidebar?

Comment: *random guess* Does the `<refresh>` function help?

Comment: Aha. `ctrl-l` works. But <refresh> to the macro is giving me "<redraw-screen>: unknown variable"

Answer (score 5):

Seems I was looking for [`redraw-screen`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/)

```
macro pager b "<enter-command>toggle sidebar_visible <enter><redraw-screen>"
```