# Mutt shows scrambled characters in white space after folder change

Tags: mutt

For switching accounts in mutt I user folder hooks through a macro like:

```
folder-hook 'google.com'  'source ~/.mutt/account.gmail.muttrc'
macro index <f2> '<sync-mailbox><enter-command>source \
~/.mutt/account.gmail.muttrc<enter><change-folder>!<enter>'
```

After every switch my terminal displays not deleted characters in empty areas behind the mail topic and body text.

How can I clear my display after each account or folder switch?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274537/175245) answer but didn't find it; so I got the [same answer](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/). Adding `<redraw-screen>` at the end will do the trick.

```
macro index <f2> '<sync-mailbox><enter-command>source \
~/.mutt/account.gmail.muttrc<enter><change-folder>!<enter><redraw-screen>'
```

Comment: This sounds more like a workaround than a fix. It sounds like your TERM is broken/misconfigured...

Comment: That might be the case. I use zsh with terminator and iTerm.